# Can't toggle light component in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script attached to led1 as shown in the image below. It's sole purpose is to detect when I click an LED and toggle the child "led1 light. Detecting the clicked LED works perfectly fine with Raycast, however trying to toggle the LED on and off does not work with a simple `light.enabled = !light.enable` but it does work if I do `light.enabled = true` or `light.enabled = false`. This confuses me so much, because I can see no reason for this happening. Anyone know why I cannot toggle it simply?

[image]

This code does not work in any way for turning anything on.

```
void Update()
{
    // On left mouse click 
    const int left_mouse_click = 0;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(left_mouse_click))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 600.0f))
        {
            if (hit.transform != null)
            {
                GameObject led = hit.transform.gameObject;
                Light light = led.transform.GetChild(light_source_child).GetComponent<Light>();

                // This code does not work for anything
                light.enabled = !light.enabled;
}
```

This code works for turning the LED on, but it's of course not toggled off again.

```
void Update()
{
    // On left mouse click 
    const int left_mouse_click = 0;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(left_mouse_click))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 600.0f))
        {
            if (hit.transform != null)
            {
                GameObject led = hit.transform.gameObject;
                Light light = led.transform.GetChild(light_source_child).GetComponent<Light>();

                // Works for turning LED on
                light.enabled = true;
}
```

I have implemented a solution that works, but it's very cumbersome as I have to look up in a dictionary, when it seemingly should be very simple to achieve toggling of the object.

Comment: Just use an if condition

Comment: @John Could you elaborate? I have tried a simple toggle if statement, but it still won't work.

Comment: if(light.enabled == true)

Comment: This code doesn't work either:

`if (light.enabled) light.enabled = false; else light.enabled = true;`

Comment: Assuming that there are no errors in the console and if you say that `light.enabled = true;` works as expected then `light.enabled = !light.enabled;` should actually do the trick ... Besides that you might want to rather use `hit.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Light>(true);`

Comment: Try changing the intensity of your light. that will work

Comment: @Ankit I don't see why this would work, however I tried and it is the same result.

Comment: @derHugo I'm also thinking it should have worked. I tried using variations of `hit.gameObjectlGetComponentInChildren<Light>(true);` as well, that did not work.

Comment: @C.K. Can I see that you've done? I mean your code

Comment: @Ankit if you mean the intenisty part I do `for (int led = 0; led < 64;) gameObject.transform.GetChild(led).GetChild(light_source).GetComponent<Light>().intensity = intensity;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I have several led objects and i had the script connected to every single one of them. That caused it to execute 64 times and technically the code worked, but being an even number it looked like nothing was happening, and it was obviously error prone. So moving the script up to the top parent object and using the code `light.enable = !light.enable;` worked!

Answer (score 2):

What if you don't get the Light Component, but instead replace it with the GameObject Component.

**Old Code:**

```
GameObject led = hit.transform.gameObject;
Light light = led.transform.GetChild(light_source_child).GetComponent<Light>();
```

**New Code using Transform:**

```
foreach (Transform child in hit.transform)
    //Assigns the first child of the Hit Game Object
    GameObject light = child.GetChild(0).gameObject;
```

**Disable/Enable GameObejct:**

```
// This code should work now
light.SetActive(!light.activeSelf);
```

Comment: This throws me the error that `GameObject does not contain 'enabled'`

Comment: What if you replace it with .SetActive?

Comment: It compiles but throws an argument exception at runtime `GetComponent requires that the requested component 'GameObject' dervies from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface`

Comment: What if you take the led GameObject again `GameObject led = hit.transform.gameObject;` and then `GameObject light = led.GetComponentInChildren<GameObject>();`

Comment: I tried a new Method you can see it under, New Code using Transform:

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have solved the issue!